# Python: How to get multiple entries from listbox?

Tags: python, user-interface, listbox, tkinter, selection

I'd like to get all file names in a directory and present them to user in a listbox, then user may choose multiple names and press OK or Cancel. If he presses OK, it should return selected file names. Please help.

Comment: I disagree with this question being put on hold as off-topic. This question has become a nice tutorial about tkinter listbox widget, which will possibly help many novice python programmers.

Comment: @Bryan Read the description below 'off topic'.

Comment: Are you specifically asking about presenting the names in a listbox, or would a standard file dialog work? Both are possible, it's just not clear what you really need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a fairly simple way using [Tkinter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html):

```
from Tkinter import *


root = Tk()
opt_list = ['opt1','opt2','opt3','opt4','opt5']
sel_list = []

def get_sel():
    sel_list.append(Lb1.curselection())
    root.destroy()

def cancel():
    root.destroy()

B = Button(root, text ="Submit", command = get_sel)
C = Button(root, text ="Cancel", command = cancel)
Lb1 = Listbox(root, selectmode=MULTIPLE)

for i,j in enumerate(opt_list):
    Lb1.insert(i,j)


Lb1.pack()
B.pack()
C.pack()

root.mainloop()

for i in sel_list[0]:
    print opt_list[int(i)]
```

then you can this to get the selected options:

```
for i in sel_list[0]:
    print opt_list[int(i)]
```

this will create a listbox using the items from `sel_list` then when the user presses submit it will return a tuple of which lines are selected

multiple can be selected at a time and will returned in a tuple get more information from this site [Python Tk Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm)

Comment: Window is not closed when I press "Submit" button.

Comment: you just need to call `root.destroy()` check my edit i made a few changes now it will add the selected options to `sel_list` and when you push submit it will close

Comment: And how do I get the selected values into a list?

Comment: see the new edit just use that second for loop and it will print the selected options :)

Comment: And how to add a "cancel" button to exit the gui window? :)

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, what you want is http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog

```
#python 3
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
filenames = askopenfilename(multiple=True)
```

This returns a list of paths to the files the person chose, to extract the filename:

```
import os
filenames = [os.path.basename(filename) for filename in filenames]
```

and if you want the filename without extension, instead of the line above use:

```
filenames = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0] for filename in filenames]
```